# Convert basic four digit year and month to date in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date

Surprised I can't find an answer to this, I have two very simple objects:

```
$scope.yearParams = [
        {'name':2016},
        {'name':2015},
        {'name':2014},
        {'name':2013}
    ];

$scope.dateParams = [
        {
            'name':'DECEMBER', 
            'dataNumber':12 
        },
        {
            'name':'NOVEMBER', 
            'dataNumber':11 
        },
        {
            'name':'OCTOBER', 
            'dataNumber':10 
        },
        ...
    ];
```

I would like to convert both of these to date objects, but only return 'yyyy' for year and 'MMMM' for month, but I don't think angular can take a four digit year or string and convert it, I am assuming it would need to be something like `Wed Sep 28 2016 09:39:51 GMT+0100 (BST)`, or another full date.

I tried the following in my view:

```
<li ng-repeat="data in yearParams" data-attr="{{data.name}}">{{data.name | date:'yyyy'}}</li> // returns 1970
```

Can angular simply accept a four digit year as an input? Similarly can angular map month names to a date object, but only return 'MMMM'. Maybe this is not possible (or useful even).

I am using this so the client can run reports for different years and months and could perhaps default to the current year and month in the select (and not show Oct, Nov, Dec for 2016 etc).

Comment: why do you need to convert year (2016) into year (2016)? you already have year in object. so why do u need extra filtering?

Comment: Because for Month, it would be nice to show the current month as the selected item and then only previous months (so don't show October, November if we are still in September of the current year).

Comment: {{youryear| date:'yyyy'}} will not work if youryear = '2016' but if you create date object it will work youryear= new Date('2016'); you also pass month and year like new Date('2016-12') and use {{yourdate| date:'MMMM-yyyy'}}

Comment: you can also have a look at [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com) it very powerfull for handling date and time